# Access denied while loading from gcs to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have uploaded a csv file to gcs and I can list/view that file using "gsutil(ls and cat)". I can even load that file using "bq load" but when I try to load it from the python loadTable script mentioned in the examples, it fails with the error message "Access Denied"

```
{u'state': u'DONE', u'errors': [{u'reason': u'accessDenied', u'message': u'Access Denied: File (file_name): Access Denied'}], u'errorResult': {u'reason': u'accessDenied', u'message': u'Access Denied: File (file_name): Access Denied'}}
```

Done Loading!

The authorization used is through "Service account" key. I have tested the listing of dataset and the table. Its just the upload through gcs which says "Access Denied".

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the service account have read access to the google storage file? Can you send the job id of the failed load job?

Comment: I did not note the jobId of the failed load job. I reran the load job again which failed with the same error and its jobId is 
'job_b32883bcbfa54b1a82b5dfd15aad3d28'. How do we verify that the service account has read access to gcs? How do we set the access for the service account?

Comment: It was an issue with the ACL for service account. Verified it with "gsutil ls -L -b" for the bucket and assigned Read access for the service account to the gcs location. Thanks for help.